# load database sqlite bigger than 1 mb in asset folder

Tags: android, sqlite, assets

How can I load database bigger than 1 MB in asset folder? I have a database file, I copied it into asset folder and then by code , copy to data directory, but because it's bigger than 1 MB ,makes error!

Comment: Can you please post error?

Comment: Accept and close this answer if it has solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

The SQLiteAssetHelper library makes this task really simple.
The jar file and documentation are found at https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper.

As explained in documentation:

1. Add the `android-sqlite-asset-helper.jar` to your project `libs` directory.
2. Compress the database in a zip file such as `assets/databases/database_name.zip`.
3. Create a class:

Example:

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
     private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database_name";
     private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;    
     public MyDatabase(Context context) {
         super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);  
     }  
 }
```

EDIT

```
public Cursor getEmployees() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "FullName"}; 
        String sqlTables = "Employees";

        qb.setTables(sqlTables);
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null,
                null, null, null);

        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;

    }

    public int getUpgradeVersion() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        String [] sqlSelect = {"MAX (version)"};
        String sqlTables = "upgrades";

        qb.setTables(sqlTables);
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null,
                null, null, null);

        int v = 0;
        c.moveToFirst();
        if (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            v = c.getInt(0);
        }
        c.close();
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Annoymous , But how Can I decompress it in my code?

Comment: Using this library you can access the database.Check my edit.It retrieves the database from the resources folder,all you have to do is query it!.PS Accept and close this answer if it has solved your problem